# Convert months (in decimal form) to months and days that were found between two dates

Tags: google-sheets, decimal, days, date-difference

**UPDATE** - My initial question has been answered. Follow up question at the bottom.

I'm trying to find the days, months, weeks, years between two dates (today and list of birthdays).

I couldn't find the weeks using DATEDIF so I found an easier solution and used:

=ABS(TODAY()-J2) for Days

=ABS(TODAY()-J2)/7 for Weeks
=ABS(TODAY()-J2)/(365/12) for Months

You'll see that for months (K) it gives me a decimal of 1.18356 but I want it to say 1 month and 6 days. I'm not sure if you can do this in one cell so you can see I created a column (L) next to weeks hoping I could come up with a formula for it to show 6 days. The same thing happens for Weeks (M). Does anyone know how to convert this? Thank you in advance for your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmtht.png)

I'm a beginner with this so I don't have many tools to pull from. I honestly don't know where to start with this.

With the help of Gilbert I used the MOD function to use with my first question. I'm trying to perform the same calculation between the birth date and today but I'm still getting those decimals.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN0t7.png)

Is there another function I could use?

Comment: Month lengths vary.  Calculate days first, then weeks, then months.  The [MOD function](https://www.statology.org/remainder-google-sheets-mod-function/) gives you the leftover days.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Oh my goodness! Thank you! I've never heard of the mod function but I got it to work! I have a follow up question. I'm trying to calculate the same date span between today and the person's birth. I'm still getting some decimals in the cell. I'll post a new image in the original question.

Comment: [How to Calculate Age in Google Sheets](https://spreadsheetpoint.com/calculate-age-google-sheets/)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc  Thanks so much! I appreciate your help.